# Save single value connected with the same parent element searched by xPath

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I have a simple XML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<cars>
  <car>
    <name>megane2</nazwa>
    <averagefuelconsumption>2</averagefuelconsumption>
  </car>
</cars>
```

And I want to save the `averagefuelconsumption` value into a string. In the XML there are a lot of cars, but I want only one. I tried using Xpath:

```
string averagefuelconsumption = "";
string CarName = "megane2";
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(Application.StartupPath + "\\cars.xml");
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(reader);
reader.Close();
XmlElement onecar = doc.DocumentElement;
onecar.SelectSingleNode("/cars/car[name='" + CarName + "']/averagefuelconsumption");
averagefuelconsumption = onecar.Value;
```

Unfortunately, the string is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of

```
onecar.SelectSingleNode(...)
```

use

```
doc.SelectSingleNode(...)
```

in the end, you want:

```
var element = doc.SelectSingleNode("/cars/car[name='" + CarName + "']/averagefuelconsumption");
averagefuelconsumption = element.InnerText;
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the string for the XmlElement, you must you the InnerText.

```
string averagefuelconsumption = "";
string CarName = "megane2";
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(Application.StartupPath + "\\cars.xml");
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(reader);
reader.Close();
XmlElement onecar = doc.DocumentElement;
onecar.SelectSingleNode("/cars/car[name='" + CarName + "']/averagefuelconsumption");
averagefuelconsumption = onecar.InnerText;
```

also, please note that your xml is not valid as well.  It should be:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
   <cars>
     <car>
       <name>megane2</name>
       <averagefuelconsumption>2</averagefuelconsumption>
     </car>
   </cars>
```

Answer (score 0):

Has [this great example](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/93689924-230f-43df-937d-b186e2f74c41/how-to-populate-data-from-xml-file-to-custom-object-with-c?forum=xmlandnetfx) on the Microsoft Developer Network.

Answer (score 0):

This is my preferred method, even though it doesn't use XPath:

```
        string xml = @"
            <cars>
                <car>
                    <name>megane2</name>
                    <averagefuelconsumption>2</averagefuelconsumption>
                </car>
            </cars>";

        XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
        // same as XDocument.Load("your\path\to\file.xml");

        Func<string, XDocument, string> getAvgFuelConsumption = (car, xd) => xd
            .Descendants("car")
            .First(c => c.Element("name").Value == car)
            .Element("averagefuelconsumption")
            .Value;

        Console.WriteLine(getAvgFuelConsumption("megane2", xDoc));
```

Prints `2`